# How can I change an image-plot by select widget?

Tags: bokeh, python-3.7

I want to use a select-widget/slider-widget to change an image-plot. Is there a way to do that? And if "no" what are my options to realize that issue?

Here is a short example of what i've done:

```py
#Let's make some data:
image_a = np.random.randint(0,10,10000).reshape(100,100)
image_b = np.random.randint(0,10,10000).reshape(100,100)
image_c = np.random.randint(0,10,10000).reshape(100,100)


# define a callback:
def callback(attr, old, new):
    plot.image = [select_widget.value]

#create a figure:
plot = figure()

# And plot the image "image_a"
plot.image(image=[image_a])

# create a select-widget with options:
select_widget = Select(title="Title", \
                       value="image_a", \
                       options=["image_a","image_b","image_c"])

# If the widget will be changed call a callback-function to modify
# the image by selection:
select_widget.on_change('value', callback)

layout = row(select_widget, plot)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Unfortunatelly the image will not be updated as expected. Lateron i want to use a slider to load differnt images. But i'm not sure, if i can do that.

Maybe there is another way to plot an numpy-array?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running this as a Bokeh server app, i.e. with `bokeh serve`? Real python callbacks only work in the context of a Bokeh server application (the Bokeh server is exactly the Python process that runs the Python callback code). Otherwise, if this is standalone content (i.e. with `output_file` and `show`) then only JavaScript `CustomJS` callbacks are possible.

There are many examples of using `CustomJS` callbacks that update plots in the User's Guide chapter: [JavaScript Callbacks](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html)

There are many examples of real Python callbacks used in Bokeh server applications in the [`examples/app`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app) folder of the GitHub repo. You should also consider studying the [Running a Bokeh Server](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) chapter of the User's Guide. It was written to provide exactly this kind of background.

In any case, the code you have above will not function in either case. The *value* of the select widget is a *string*, i.e. "image_a", so your callback is doing the equivalent of:

```
plot.image = ["image_a"]
```

which is obviously nonsensical. You would need the contents of the list to be an actual array. Assuming this is a Bokeh server app (so that real Python callbacks can work), you could use a dict to map the strings to the actual arrays:

```
data = {
     "image_a": image_a,
     "image_b": image_b,
     "image_c": image_c,
}
```

Then:

```
plot.image = [data[select_widget.value]]
```

Comment: Oh yes I do! I run this in a Bokeh server.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion to map string names to actual arrays?

Comment: Ok, now it works very well. But i've implemented an color mapper and a color bar and these objects are not adjusted.

Comment: Not sure offhand, but please ask distinct questions in separate topics, otherwise things get very hard to follow.